# Conditional formatting with if-else statements in Swift

Tags: swift, uikit

I have a view controller with 6 text fields (A, B, C, D, E, F) and two buttons at the bottom (‘cancel’ and ‘add’).

I am trying to apply conditional formatting which enables ‘add’ button only in case if either:

1)    A, B, C, D and **E** are filled in at the same time; or

2)    A, B, C, D and **F** are filled in at the same time.

The problem is with **E** and **F**. The user has a choice to either:

1)    fill in E (with fixed options [the text field has a pickerView as an input view); or

2)    fill in F (with whatever text she prefers).

Please help me with setting up the logic of it all.

This is what I have:

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if A.text != nil && A.text != "" { addButton.isEnabled = true } else { addButton.isEnabled = false }
    if B.text != nil && B.text != "" { addButton.isEnabled = true } else { addButton.isEnabled = false }
    if C.text != nil && C.text != "" { addButton.isEnabled = true } else { addButton.isEnabled = false }
    if D.text != nil && D.text != "" { addButton.isEnabled = true } else { addButton.isEnabled = false }
    if E.text != nil && E.text != "" && F.text == "" { addButton.isEnabled = true } else { addButton.isEnabled = false }
    if F.text != nil && F.text != "" && E.text == "" { addButton.isEnabled = true } else { addButton.isEnabled = false }
}
```

I am sensing that the last two if-else statements might contradict each other, making the addButton.isEnabled always false. Hence, my addButton is never enabled.

Probably the last two if-else statements should be combined into a single statement somehow, maybe using ||. Any ideas?

Also now that I think of it, what if my user decides to fill in both E and F. I think I’m gonna crash. So that should also be prevented through the if-else logic.

Comment: How to write an if-else statement that would satisfy the mentioned requirements for E and F textFields. That's what I meant

Comment: @user398509 instead of adding a comment, please [edit] your question with any additional info. See also [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not set `addButton.isEnabled` only after checking one text field, like you are doing here.

Check all the text fields, and then set `addButton.isEnabled`.

If I understand correctly, you want the add button to be enabled *if and only if*:

- Text fields A, B, C, D, E are not empty, and F is empty

  OR
- Text fields A, B, C, D, F are not empty, and E is empty

Once you spell out the conditions *precisely*, putting that into code is trivial:

```
let addButtonShouldBeEnabled = (
    A.hasText &&
    B.hasText &&
    C.hasText &&
    D.hasText &&
    E.hasText &&
    !F.hasText
) || (
    A.hasText &&
    B.hasText &&
    C.hasText &&
    D.hasText &&
    !E.hasText &&
    F.hasText
)
addButton.isEnabled = addButtonShouldBeEnabled
```

Or course, we could simplify the condition a bit by using some boolean identities.

```
let addButtonShouldBeEnabled =
    A.hasText &&
    B.hasText &&
    C.hasText &&
    D.hasText &&
    E.hasText != F.hasText
```

The `!=` here acts like an boolean XOR.

Comment: `UIKeyInput` has a property called [`hasText`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uikeyinput/1614457-hastext) note also that UITextField text property will NEVER return nil. Its default value is an empty string

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks. I didn't know about `hasText`. Are you sure about `text` never returning nil? The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield/1619635-text) says "This value is nil by default.", and I definitely remember getting a nil from it at some point.

Comment: `UILabel` can return nil but `UITextField` will always return an empty string even if you assign `nil` to `text` before getting its value.

Comment: I will double check it when I get back to my machine but I think the documentation has changed.

Answer (score 1):

What about creating a computed property for checking the first four fields since they are always required

```
var abcdIsFilled: Bool {
     A.text!.isEmpty == false &&
     B.text!.isEmpty == false &&
     C.text!.isEmpty == false &&
     D.text!.isEmpty == false
}
```

and then use it with a `guard` statement

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    guard abcdIsFilled else {
         addButton.isEnabled = false
         return
    }

    if E.text!.isEmpty == false && F.text!.isEmpty ||
       F.text!.isEmpty == false && E.text!.isEmpty {
        addButton.isEnabled = true
    } else {
        // both are filled...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with:

```
// Check if mandatories fields are not empty
let mandatoryFields: [UITextField] = [A, B, C, D]
guard !mandatoryFields.contains(where { $0.text?.isEmpty ?? true } else {
    addButton.isEnabled = false
    return
}

//Check only E & F, one has to be NOT empty AND the other one is empty, so their isEmpty needs to be opposite
let eText = E.text ?? ""
let fText = F.text ?? ""
guard eText.isEmpty != fText.isEmpty else { //Both are empties or has text
    addButton.isEnabled = false
    return
}

//We passed all the tests
addButton.isEnabled = true
```